# C++ & SDL : No error but Images won't draw

Tags: c++, image, sdl

I have been following a tutorial on SDL Game Development to get back into C++. And yesterday I ran into an odd error. `My image should be drawn to the window. But it doesn't appear in any form`. `I did a bit of debugging and the image is in fact loaded into the program`. It just won't draw. I decided to come back to it today.

After some digging, it would seem that it is the `SDL rectangles used in the Game class` are the problem. `I figured this out by printing the width of the destination rectangle and it came out as 0`. Perhaps I missed something. I have pasted a link to the project as the `Game class consists of a Header and a CPP`. Can you see where I went wrong?

https://app.box.com/s/fa7nvji36bulcmb36p72

Not going for gold medal programming, just trying to get things to work so I can continue with the rest of the chapter.

Any help is kindly appreciated. I have also posted all code related to the image below.

---Game.H---

```
#ifndef __Game__ 
#define __Game__

#include "SDL.h"

class Game
{
    public:
        Game();
        ~Game();
        bool init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen);
        void render();
        void update();
        void mainGameLoop();
        void clean();
        void loadImages();
        bool running();
    private:
        bool g_running;
        SDL_Window* window;
        SDL_Renderer* renderer;
        SDL_Texture* m_pTexture; // the new SDL_Texture variable
        SDL_Rect m_sourceRectangle; // the first rectangle
        SDL_Rect m_destinationRectangle; // another rectangle
};

#endif /* defined(__Game__) */
```

---Game.cpp (Extracts)---

```
void Game::loadImages() //Called in the Constructor (Testing purposes)
{
    SDL_Surface* pTempSurface = SDL_LoadBMP("assets/sprites/rider.bmp"); //Loads the Image

    if (pTempSurface == NULL)
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Image Loaded" << endl;

    m_pTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, pTempSurface); //Creates the texture//CHECK
    SDL_FreeSurface(pTempSurface); //Frees the surface

    SDL_QueryTexture(m_pTexture, NULL, NULL,&m_sourceRectangle.w, &m_sourceRectangle.h); //Sets the width and height of the source Rectangle
    m_sourceRectangle.x = 0;
    m_sourceRectangle.y = 0;

    m_destinationRectangle.x = 0; //Prepares the destination and source co-ordinates
    m_destinationRectangle.y = 0;
    m_destinationRectangle.w = m_sourceRectangle.w; 
    m_destinationRectangle.h = m_sourceRectangle.h;

    cout << m_destinationRectangle.w << endl; //Proves that the problem is here.
}

void Game::render()
{
    // set to black
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    // clear the window to black
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, m_pTexture, &m_sourceRectangle,&m_destinationRectangle); //Draws the sprite

    // show the window
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

Perhaps someone else can see what I am failing to see.

Comment: `SDL_FreeSurface(pTempSurface);` try to delete this line.

Comment: Didn't work. Good idea though.

Comment: Hmm... and `SDL_QueryTexture` does not returns an error code?

Comment: Nope, the code works as normal. Is there anyway to detect the success/fail of the function?

Comment: [SDL Wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/). Almost all of the SDL functions return an `int` value which shows the result of the call. By default, SDL functions return `0` if a function call passed successfully and some negative values otherwise.

Comment: By the way, do you use a single thread in your project or multithreading?

Comment: It is a single thread. Not going to over-complicate it atm.

Interesting comment about the SDL Wiki. I will post the outcome tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error isn't where you think it is at all, but is due to the fact that the`Game::loadImages`function is executed before SDL and the rendering context have been properly initialized, so when you try to load create the texture from the surface, the renderer is invalid. If you had checked the return value from the`SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface()`call the `SDL_Error()`function would have told you exactly that.

What you need to do is to either move the call to `Game::init()` that you have in main to the constructor of the Game class, or maybe move the call to `Game::loadImages()` to to `Game::init()` function.

In any case you need to initialize SDL before you start to load images.

Comment: ARGH!!!! How did I miss that?! JPW please slap me as I'm clearly not right in the head with programming. Thanks for everything!

Comment: @JeremyBeare Haha, it's always the small things that we look over :) Always check return codes and you'll save many hours in the future :)